# Cloning a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, glut, deep-copy

I have some structs like the below:

```
typedef struct {
    GLubyte red, green, blue;
} pixel;

typedef struct {
    pixel *pixelData;
    int w, h;
} imagen;
```

It's for an image loader and image processor (applies filters to a loaded image).

I'm initializing two `imagen`:

```
imagen work, original;
```

`work` is something that I want to display after having some filters applied, and `original` is something I can reset to.

```
void loadImage() {
    //load data into (imagen)original
}
work = original;
```

After loading the image, I copy it to `work` so I can maintain a copy of the original should I want to reset later (reset being `work = original` again). The problem I'm facing is that the reset doesn't work: anything I apply to `work` is also applied to `original`, so I'm effectively resetting to what I'm resetting.

I think the problem is my `work = original`; I'm fairly new to C, but I'm assuming I'm only pointing `work` at `original`, so any logic I do on `work` is also applied to `original`?

```
original.w = 40;
work = original;
work.w = 50;
work = original;
```

Is `work.w` 40 or 50 in this case? If it is indeed pointing to original, how do I instead clone `original` onto `work`, so I can safely work on `work` without consequence of `original`?

Comment: You want to do a "deep-copy" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of the source `struct` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `pixelData` pointer in your struct:

```
typedef struct {
    pixel *pixelData;
    int w, h;
} imagen;
```

In order to create a completely independent copy, you need to copy the data `pixelData` is pointing to:

```
work.w = original.w;
work.h = original.h;
size_t size = sizeof(pixel) * work.w * work.h;
work.pixelData = (pixel*)malloc(size);
memcpy(original.pixelData, work.pixelData, size);
```

Also note that when you no longer need it you have to release the allocated memory:

```
free(work.pixelData);
```

Comment: No need to cast `malloc()` in C.

Comment: Cheers, this helps a lot. Just a correction: `memcpy(original.pixelData, work.pixelData, size);` should be `memcpy(work.pixelData, original.pixelData, size);`,

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the pointer to pixeldata. When you assign it, you are copying the address of the value stored in original, and once you modify it with, the original is modified too. Try allocating a new pixelData pointer and then copy the original content in its value, instead of copying the pointed address itself.